# Between the twins when laughing

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> My family is everywhere,
> Giant and small, as fitting,
> I rarely live just by myself,
> With my kin I'll be keeping.
>
> Between the twins when I need help,
> Between the twins when laughing,
> Beside the knight when I agree,
> Beside the knight when falling.
>
> Here I'll be seen with my bare head,
> Away I'll wear my helmet,
> My presence is quite rarely shunned,
> But still, we haven't met yet.

I am...?

Comment: Oh-My! The clickbait title...

Comment: cmon, somebody post the answer we all want

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You are

> the letter 'o'.

My family is everywhere,
Giant and small, as fitting,
I rarely live just by myself,
With my kin I'll be keeping.

> Letters are everywhere, capital and lowercase, and generally found in groups.

Between the twins when I need help,

> SOS

Between the twins when laughing,

> lol

Beside the knight when I agree,

> OK (the knight = Kay, one of the Knights of the Round Table (via @GarethMcCaughan))

Beside the knight when falling.

> KO (boxing, knock-out)

Here I'll be seen with my bare head,

> English o's (usually) have no diacritical marks.

Away I'll wear my helmet,

> Non-english o's often do. (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Variations_of_%22o%22#Diacritics)

My presence is quite rarely shunned,

> it's a common letter.

But still, we haven't met yet.

> There are no o's in the riddle or title!

Comment: Looks great! I was just wondering if it could be a letter

Comment: "K" standing for "knight" seems OK to me. But one of the KotRT was called Kay, so perhaps that's who you have in mind.